# How to search for a set of specific vales of values in inputs of one table, against the other table's id(s) values to add css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 forms on the same page. One is called from 'A'. Other one is called form 'B'.

Form A is dynamically loaded with the values getting from a database.

Form B has 56 inputs. Each input of form B has unique ids' which are the values of form A's inputs. Number of inputs

appearing on form 'A' may be different due to client's previous requests.

Form 'A's all inputs have the same name (Aname) but values are different.

Each and every input of form 'A' has a value and also in form 'B' you can find a corresponding input for each value from form

'B'. The css class of the inputs of form 'A', should apply for each corresponding input of form'B'.

The fact is: form A's inputs' values have been printed as the id(s) of each input of form 'B'.

Number of inputs of form B is fixed. That is "56".

Number of generated inputs of form A may be different from one user to another. Anyhow the maximum number of inputs of form A is also "56".

For example,
enter code here

```
<form name="A">
<input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="2" disabled="disabled" class="red">
<input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="5" disabled="disabled" class="red">
<input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="3" disabled="disabled" class="red">
</form>
<form name="B">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="1" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="2" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="3" data-assetid="1">
   <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="4" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="5" data-assetid="1">
    </form>
```

Accordingly the example, the css class "red" should be applied on form 'B's first, third and fifth inputs.

How can I do this with jQuery please?

Comment: do you mean B'` 2nd, 3rd and 5th inputs

Comment: Those are only for examples! If the vales matches with id's of the other table, class should be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```js
$("form[name='A'] input").each(function(){
    $("#"+this.value).addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.red{
    background:red;
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="A">
    <input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="2" disabled="disabled" class="red">
    <input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="5" disabled="disabled" class="red">
    <input type="text" name="alreadybooked" value="3" disabled="disabled" class="green">
</form>
<form name="B">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="1" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="2" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="3" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="4" data-assetid="1">
    <input type="button" value="0" class="btn-submit" id="5" data-assetid="1">
</form>
```